# Show 3d object on device live camera in Unity3d for iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, textures, vuforia

How can I render a 3d or 2d (.jpg or .png) object at device live camera in Unity3d? This 3d object shouldn't be stuck to the camera. It has to show at specific point, like we can set any object in game scene at particular location.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you actually have your device camera's texture rendered in Unity?

Comment: Actually i am new bee in Unity3d, I am following ImageTarget Sample Project Vuforia. What i have i am showing 2d texture but this is stuck with camera device. But I need which shouldn't stuck with camera.

Comment: Stuck how?  Can you show an example?

Comment: Like what I need. I want to show Image at specific radius and specific angle(N,S,E,W) when user reach at that place and holding device to let say North side then i have to show image but this should not stuck with camera if I move camera then it shouldn't move any where.

Comment: I would like to help but your question is directly related to the Vuforia plugin, not necessarily Unity itself.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you just give hint, other than vuforia plugin. Its also a general problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22399/discussion-between-jerdak-and-josh)

Comment: I have done work using vuforia not for unity but for ios, if you paste some code that you think will help us answer your question, please do. but the vuforia library is quite complex and your question is quite vague. so long as you know your opengl/unity stuff well enough, you shouldnt have a problem integrating it with the vuforia stuff, their examples are really good